# Is `unique_ptr::operator bool()` defined for a unique_ptr that has been move()d from?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, std

It is my understanding that after I have moved from a Standard Library object, that object is in a state that is valid but undefined. But in the case of a `unique_ptr`, just how undefined is it? Empirically, the code below seems to work, that is, after I move from `p1`, "`if ( p1 )`" evaluates false. Intuitively, this seems like the correct behavior. But can I rely on this?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    using namespace std;

    unique_ptr<int> p1 {make_unique<int>(1)};
    unique_ptr<int> p2;

    if ( p1 )
        cout << "p1 owns an object" << endl;
    if ( p2 )
        cout << "p2 owns an object" << endl;

    p2 = move(p1);

    // Is the following test valid, now that p1 has been moved from?
    if ( p1 )
        cout << "p1 owns an object" << endl;
    if ( p2 )
        cout << "p2 owns an object" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
p1 owns an object
p2 owns an object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `unique_ptr`'s specification explicitly states that the effect of move operations on such pointers is *transfer of ownership* from the right-hand side pointer to the left-hand side pointer (20.8.1/16 for move constructor, 20.8.1.2.3/2 for assignment). The concept of *transfer of ownership* is explicitly defined in the standard (20.8.1/4) and it says that the right-hand side becomes *nullptr* after such transfer.

This means that the state or moved-from `unique_ptr` is not just valid, it is *defined*.

Answer (score 1):

> can I rely on this?

Yes you can. Move on a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) means transferring ownership from it, and then `operator bool` will return `false` certainly since it doesn't own any object.